# Парсинг строки фрейма данных

Tags: python, парсер, pandas

Есть фрейм данных `movies` со столбцом `title`, в котором содержатся строки с названием и года выпуска фильма. Например:

> Stanley Kubrick: A Life in Pictures (2001)

Задача: создать переменную `years` со списком всех годов с 1950 по 2010.

Как я могу распарсить строки данного столбца, чтобы вычленить оттуда год?

Думаю обернуть всё это в функцию, чтобы потом применить к `df` и создать новый столбец.

В примере лекции показан метод `from urllib import parse`, но он применим к ссылкам URL, не к строкам, насколько я понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.str.extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) чтобы вычленить год выпуска из наименования фильма.

PS надеюсь с регулярным выражением справитесь сами)

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось!